# Are there any accessories that can protect my camera from high voltage flash guns?

Tags: flash, equipment-damage, hotshoe-flash, hotshoe

I use some older flashes that have a lot higher trigger voltages and may damage my newer cameras if used in the hot shoe mount. Therefore as a precaution I use the PC sync with them instead and mount them on a cold shoe adapter that rests in the hot shoe of my camera. By doing this there is no potential high voltage connection between my camera and flash.

Are there any accessories (possibly using a surge protector) that I can put in my hot shoe and let me use the old flash guns protecting my camera from possible harm?

Comment: When you say you use the PC sync, do I understand correctly that you plug a cable between the flash and the camera ? Is this not as risky as plugging the flash directly on the hotshoe ? While on older cameras the sync was done mechanically (in link to the shutter), on more recent ones I suspect this is electronics.

Comment: @FredP Yes, you've understood me correctly but the flashes I use have low voltage PC sync (it's specified as 8.5 V on my hot shoe flash and I think 6 V on a strobe that I'd like to trigger from my hot shoe using a wireless trigger instead). I also have a third one that doesn't specify the voltage so I have not dared to try it.

Comment: Ok, thanks (I'm not very familiar with older flashes).

Comment: @FredP Me neither, but your question is valid since the voltage often is the same in the PC sync

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the Wein Safesync is designed to do exactly that:

http://www.weinproducts.com/safesyncs.htm